# Hacer ventana modal tipo wallapop en ios con swift

Tags: ios, swift

Necesito saber si es posible hacer esta ventana modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado hacerlo con custom segues pero no me funciona

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con swift??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy simple. Lo primero que tienes que hacer es un `scale` del `rootViewController.view` en el `AppDelegate` para hacerlo más pequeño. De esta forma, conseguirás tener ese fondo negro que corresponde al `window` principal.

Después, para la pantalla que está por delante, haz un modal en el que el `UITableView` de los filtros empiece a unos `60 px` del `top`. Entonces, el fondo lo pones transparente.
Lo único que faltará es que el `modalPresentationStyle` sea de tipo `Custom`

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido de gran ayuda @mhergon